# Choosing types based on condition

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know that in Typescript we can create a variable which can be one of the passed types.

`const variable: string | number;`

Is there a way to set a variable with two array types and based on some condition we can choose one of the arrays?

For example:

```
interface DataOne {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface DataTwo {
  name: string;
  data: string;
}

let exampleArray = [];

const example: DataOne[] | DataTwo[];
```

Condition:

If exampleArray is empty choose DataOne[] else DataTwo[] something like that.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that `exampleArray` can be a fixed set:

```
const exampleArray = [] as const;
```

Then you can enquire about it's emptiness using a conditional:

```
type Example<T extends readonly any[]> = T[0] extends undefined ? DataOne[] : DataTwo[];
```

Above checks that if index 0 of the argument is undefined then array is empty and it should choose `DataOne` and otherwise `DataTwo`.

so now if you have:

```
const exampleArray = [1] as const;
const ex: Example<typeof exampleArray> = []; // will be DataTwo[]
```

and if you have

```
const exampleArray = [] as const;
const ex: Example<typeof exampleArray> = []; // will be DataOne[]
```

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. Can I ask you if this kind of check can be performed on object. Let say if property "example" exist choose DataOne[] else DataTwo[]

Comment: No, run time checking is beyond the scope of typescript. You will need to use things like runtypes for that

Comment: https://github.com/pelotom/runtypes